# SQL Alchemy creates new object with existing Primary key

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create new object in sqlalchemy but getting integrity error because that ID is already exist. Below is my model.

```
class RFBOpportunityDetail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rfb_opportunity_detail'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
```

I am using postgreSQL Database and that table already have entries. below is code to create new object.

```
models.RFBOpportunityDetail(name=name, code=code)
```

Is there anything which i should know about creating a new object with SQLalchemy or PostgreSQL?

Error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "fbo_all_opportunity_detail_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(221418) already exists
```

Comment: Do you mean that a row with the same `code` already exists? And what would you like to happen, if it does. You're not using primary keys anywhere in your example. You've provided neither possible tracebacks from raised exceptions, nor example data. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @IljaEverilä updated post with error.... no this error is not because code already exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution seems like there was some issue with postgres as i imported data through sql. i used below command to resolve this issue

```
SELECT setval('rfb_opportunity_detail_id_seq', MAX(id)) FROM rfb_opportunity_detail;
```